# Algorithm Design for Delaunay Triangulation?

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, triangulation

I am very much happy after seeing some very good answers in this site. I am trying to design a algorithm for the construction of
 [Delaunay Triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation)
using Randomized Incremental Algorithm.(I wont expect everyone to know about this one), I need to design a triangle which stores points,edges and the triangles adjacent to it,also need to maintain a parent & children relation between the triangles and also edges with two opposite points to each of it(preferably in java) . I know its a bit complicated and not easy to understand but i cant explain the whole algorithm here in this site, so i would like to find some one who is familiar with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look at Lutz Kettner's paper,
"Designing a Data Structure for Polyhedral Surfaces,"
([CiteSeer link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.33.5436)).
He uses the [half-edge data structure](http://openmesh.org/Documentation/OpenMesh-2.0-Documentation/mesh_hds.html). Here is [CGAL's description](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/HalfedgeDS/Chapter_main.html) of that structure:

     
[image]
An alternative is the [winged-edge data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winged_edge).

Comment: For triangulations, you can you a simpler alternative such as described in http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/TDS_2/Chapter_main.html#Subsection_38.1.1

Comment: I am very happy on seeing your answer thank you @Joseph

Comment: See also https://doi.org/10.1016/S0925-7721(99)00007-3, which seems to be the journal version of that paper